# woocommerce product widget showing mysterious class that I can't style

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, css-selectors, responsive

[Edit added this image to show what i'd like it like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEUDy.png)  Good evening. I'm working at setting up a shop in woocommerce. It's an LED Lighting Store, and I built a custom plugin for finding automotive bulbs for specific vehicles. You can check it out [here](https://www.ledlightupgrade.com/product-category/automotive/). when you select a vehicle, the results display the woocommerce widgets for all the lights that fit that vehicle. However, It's cramping them up like it's putting them in three columns. When i use the dev tools inspector to inspect the actual widget, I notice that it has a class of .products .columns-3 and I can't figure out where it is coming from. And if I call that class in CSS and try to change the number of columns, it doesn't work. Even if I use the !important tag. I've got it slightly better by commanding all the results into two columns, and reverting the box-sizing and it doesn't look too bad on desktop, but on mobile, it is really bad.  So I was wondering if you could take a look at it and possibly advise me on a solution?

Comment: Do you want it to be in just 1 column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest issue I see is that whatever is generating those results it's not separating the results into sections.  It is literally just a list of `p`. See below:

[image]

As it is now, The best way to show it would be to add this to your CSS which should put everything into 1 column and make it mobile friendly.

```
    #abf_results {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Ok perfect. Thanks a lot for answering that for me and I'll give it a try once I get back on it.

Comment: Ok so I did that and it puts it into one column, which is fine, but it still cramps it up, like the results are cramped into 3 columns, with the right two being empty. If I remove the "products columns-3" class in the dev tools, it makes it appear correctly.  And i added an edit to the original post showing a screenshot of how I'd actually like it to appear. when i just removed that class in the html on the dev tools. If we would make it output the results in sections, or divs, would that make a difference in how it appears?

Comment: Here add this to your CSS. this should make it look a lot better. `.abf_results_item *{
   display: contents;}`

Comment: Hey  that worked out great. Thanks a million for helping me out!

Comment: No problem! glad to help.